# Unmarshal JSON into struct - type of list within a list?

Tags: go, type-conversion, unmarshalling

I am trying to unmarshal a JSON object into a struct in Go. Here is the JSON object:

```
{"configuration": {
        "current power source": "",
        "sensor catalogue": [[], [], [], []],
        "actuator catalogue": [[], [], [], []],
        "active interface": ""
    }
}
```

And here is the struct in Go:

```
type Data struct{
Configuration struct {
            CurrentPowerSource string `json: "current power source"`
            SensorCatalogue  //what is the type in Go for list within a list?
            ActuatorCatalogue //each list within the list has a different type
            ActiveInterface string `json: "active interface"`
        }
}
```

My question is, how do I represent the **type** of list within a list in Go (in `sensor catalogue` and `actuator catalogue`)? When I fill my JSON object up with values, it'll look something like this:

```
{"sensor catalogue": [["temperature", "humidity"], ["dht22"], [17], ["digital"]]}
```

What is the proper way to unmarshal this?

Comment: that can be slice of slice of empty interface: `[][]interface{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what types are within the inner slices.

Arbitrary types? Use `[][]interface{}`

```
type Data struct{
    Configuration struct {
        CurrentPowerSource string 
        SensorCatalogue    [][]interface{}
        ActuatorCatalogue  [][]interface{}
        ActiveInterface    string 
    }
}
```

String types? Use `[][]string`

```
type Data struct{
    Configuration struct {
        CurrentPowerSource string 
        SensorCatalogue    [][]string
        ActuatorCatalogue  [][]string
        ActiveInterface    string 
    }
}
```

Custom types? Use `[][]CustomType`

```
type Data struct{
    Configuration struct {
        CurrentPowerSource string 
        SensorCatalogue    [][]CustomType
        ActuatorCatalogue  [][]CustomType
        ActiveInterface    string 
    }
}
```

You get the idea...